# Conditional import of worksheets in excel

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have a significant number of items that require different forms to be requested. An excerpt of the table I have looks like this:

```
    1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9   10  11  12  13  14
A   -   -   C   -   -   -   -   -   C   -   -   -   -   -
B   -   -   -   -   C   -   C   -   -   -   -   -   -   C
```

Meaning that for Item A I must enclose forms 3 and 9; for Item B, forms 5,7 and 14.

Is it possible to generate a workbook with the title of the item that contains the relevant forms as sheets.

(the forms themselves are simple excel sheets that can be renamed/manipulated as required)

Any help at all would be greatly appreciated as there are hundreds of items and tens of forms and so manually importing the sheets for each item in turn would be extremely time consuming!

Thanks

Comment: ,, your question is little confusing,,,, what i got is that you want to import Sheet based on the Cell values,, or any different idea ??

Comment: Yes, so I would have a master workbook with sheet1,2,3 etc and then generate a workbook for item A that would copy sheets 3 and 9 from the master workbook

Comment: Hi Sam, can you give us a bit more information. Will there be 1 workbook with a number of sheets where each sheet tab is labelled with the title of the form. Where are the forms to start with (different workbooks or all in the same workbook)? and where do the titles come from?

Comment: Currently there is 1 workbook with many sheets, each of which is a form. Separtely there is a table that contains a list of every item and a "-" under each form that is not needed and a "C" under each form that is. Historically we have manually created a portfolio for each item by looking at the table and copying the relevent sheets into a new document by hand. Hundreds of items have just been sent to us in one go and so I was trying to work out a way to automate this job.  Many thanks

Comment: OK - so you will start with a single master workbook and then split it into a number of different workbooks based on the table in your question. Is this correct?

Comment: `for each onecell in range("a1:b14") : if onecell="C" then set newsheet = newworkbook.sheets.add : newsheet.name = func(onecell.column) : end if : next`

Comment: Clinton, yes, although it would requrie copying rather than just splitting as many forms are required by more than one item.

Comment: @Akina - is that your answer? Comments are not meant for answers

Comment: @ChrisRogers No, it is extreme draft. Idea. Maybe somebody will convert it into solution if it is safe - I'm too lazy...

Comment: @SamWall,, what you are trying is possible using VBA (Macro) code ,,, can u handle it ?

Comment: @RajeshS, I am keen to give it a go! I have experience with simple marcos.

Comment: @SamWall  Okay give me some time to test it  first,, soon return to you !

Comment: @SamWall,, I can suggest you Macro will copy multiple sheets to new Wbook,,, but macro will not read  the Sheet Names from Cell,,, will it work for you just confirm !!

Comment: I have made a macro that, for each item in turn, will copy all sheets across into a new workbook which is titled the same as the item, the macro then goes through new workbooks and can delete sheets with specific names. I think the final function is to cross reference entries of "C" with the row heading and therefore sheet name - I am not sure how to do this

Comment: @RajeshS your macro would be great!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sam, here is a start for how to go about this interesting problem.

I set up a worksheet similar to yours except that I labelled the columns with the form names and the rows with the new Worksheet names as you can see below:

[image]

You will notice that the table with the conditions is on the first tab and the forms are on other tabs. The names on the tabs correspond exactly to the form names in row 1 of the table.

Next I went into developer mode and created a new Macro. and entered the code:

```
Sub Macro1()
'
' Macro1 Macro
' Copy sheets into new workbooks
'
'

Dim myWB As Workbook
Set myWB = ActiveWorkbook
Dim mySheet As String
Sheets(1).Select
mySheet = ActiveSheet.Name

Dim workbookName As String
Dim formName As String
For Each onecell In Range("b2:d3")
    If onecell = "C" Then
        workbookName = Cells(onecell.Row, 1).Value
        formName = Cells(1, onecell.Column).Value
        Sheets(formName).Select
        'MsgBox "WB: " & workbookName & " Form: " & formName & " Current: " & myWB.Name & ":" & mySheet
        ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(formName).Copy After:=Workbooks(workbookName).Sheets(1)
        Windows(myWB.Name).Activate
        Sheets(mySheet).Select
        MsgBox "Form: " & formName & " copied to Workbook " & workbookName
    End If
Next

End Sub
```

The in-situ macro looks like this:

[image]

This code does not do all the checks that could be done nor does it include the creation of new Workbooks (you can add this to your Macro). To get this to work, you need to create and save the blank Workbooks with the exact names that you have in the first column of the table (i.e. Workbook1.xlsx and Workbook1.xlsx in my example). These workbooks need to be open for the code to work.

Finally press 'Run' to execute the macro. You will see the following:

[image]

The message appears each time a form is copied to a Workbook. You can switch the message off by commenting it out in the code. Otherwise press 'OK' until all the forms are copied. The outcome is as follows:

[image]

That's it! I hope this helps and if you do modify the code to get to a better solution, please post it back so we can all benefit.

Comment: This is a great thanks, I will look to combine it with the macro that creates workbooks with the item names and post here when it is done.

Comment: @Clinton ,,, this Code is producing error `Script Out Of Range`  since  code is unable to find the Path for those files where Forms(sheets) are suppose to be copied,,, correct the code !!

Comment: @Rajesh - thanks for the observation. The script is intended only as a starter for Sam and not a complete solution. That would require quite a lot of more code to create new Workbooks if these do not exist and to check for user errors. Hence, the comment that the Workbooks need to be created and opened before the script is run.
The Subscript out of range occurs if the form names do not correspond exactly to the names on the tabs or if the workbooks are not opened or are incorrectly named. Please feel free to add to the code or offer a better solution.

Answer (score 1):

Thank you to all who helped, this is the final macro that I have used:

```
Sub One()
'
'Create and open workbooks of title col a & .xls
Dim masterWB As Workbook
Set masterWB = ActiveWorkbook
Dim aName As String

'set last row of items
For item = 2 To 13
    aName = masterWB.Sheets(1).Cells(item, 1).Value
    Workbooks.Add
    ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs fileName:=aName & ".xls"
    Sheets(1).Name = "Comments"

'put forms of title row 1 in workbook of title col a & .xls
    Dim myWB As Workbook
    Set myWB = ActiveWorkbook
    Dim mySheet As String
    Sheets(1).Select
    mySheet = ActiveSheet.Name

Next
masterWB.Sheets(1).Activate

Dim workbookName As String
Dim formName As String
'insert range of forms
For Each onecell In Range("d2:ae13")
    If onecell = "C" Or onecell = "II" Then

        masterWB.Sheets(1).Activate
        workbookName = Cells(onecell.row, 1).Value
        workbookName = workbookName & ".xls"

        formName = Cells(1, onecell.Column).Value
        Sheets(formName).Select
        'MsgBox "WB: " & workbookName & " Form: " & formName & " Current: " & myWB.Name & ":" & mySheet
        ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(formName).Copy After:=Workbooks(workbookName).Sheets(1)



        'reset
        Windows(myWB.Name).Activate
        Sheets(mySheet).Select
        'MsgBox "Form: " & formName & " copied to Workbook " & workbookName
    End If
Next

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for sharing your final solution to this interesting problem.